# Writing test case in JEST for array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, jestjs, testcase

Suppose countries is an array coming from a JSON file and searchTerm is input

```
// countries -> [{
//               "name": "Andorra",
//               "code": "AD"
//              },...]

//searchTerm = 'AD'

export const filterCountries = (countries, searchTerm) => {

  let filteredCountried = countries 

  if(searchTerm?.length){
    filteredCountried = countries.filter(val => {
      return val.code.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) || 
      val.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
    })
  }

  return filteredCountried
}



// in test.js file

describe('Test filterCountries', () => {
  // your solution goes here

});
```

I need to write test case for this one
any help would be appriciated

Comment: Can you share what did you try? You should cover the cases for; 1. if searchTerm exists or not 2. if code includes search term 3. if name includes search term. then you should expect expected outcome from your array.

Comment: I didn't tried anything 
I never wrote a single test case yet its my first time writing ant test case, I have no clue

Answer (score 0):

First, I recommend you to read jest documentation and start learning jest and basics. https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started

Next, what you need is, you should write cases like below; **expectedCountries** is what you expect after you filter the results.

```
describe('filterCountries', () => {
    it('should not filter countries if search term is empty', () => {
        expect(filterCountries(countries, '')).toEqual(countries);
    });

    it('should filter countries by code according to given search term', () => {
        expect(filterCountries(countries, 'AD')).toEqual(expectedCountries);
    });

    it('should filter countries by name according to given search term', () => {
        expect(filterCountries(countries, 'Andorra')).toEqual(expectedCountries);
    });

    it('should filter countries by code according to given search term case insensitive', () => {
        expect(filterCountries(countries, 'ad')).toEqual(expectedCountries);
    });

    it('should filter countries by name according to given search term case insensitive', () => {
        expect(filterCountries(countries, 'andorra')).toEqual(expectedCountries);
    });
});
```

Comment: expect(filterCountries(countries, 'AD')).toEqual(expectedCountries);

In this if multiple countries were coming, what should I pass in  "expectedCountries" making a different function or something else

Comment: The whole outcome, it's up to you to create this outcome, with a function or something.